# How do I return the index of a group of values from a list for a specific value in the group?

Tags: python, list

If I have the list:

`list1 = [(12, "AB", "CD"), (13, "EF", "GH"), (14, "IJ", "KL")]`

I want to get the index of the group that has the value 13 in it:

```
if 13 in list1[0]:
      idx = list1.index(13)
      item = list1[idx]
      print str(item)

      [13, EF, GH]
```

When I try this, I keep getting "Index not in list", even though it is passing the if statement because it is finding the value 13 within the list.

Comment: You might consider pasting the exact raised exception than describing it. That's the clearest and cleanest way. That being said, your problem is not at the if statement, but within the if block.

Comment: You are getting the error because 13 is not in `list1`. It is in `list1[1]`.

Comment: @bogatron 13 is not in `list1[0]`, it is in `list1[1]`.

Comment: `for sublst in list1: if 13 in sublst: print sublst`

Comment: Why do you want the list indices? When people ask such questions about Python it often means they intend to use those indices later. The question you need to ask yourself is do you actually care where the tuples are in the list or do you just want the tuples?

Comment: @msw you are right, I really don't care where they are in the list, I'm just trying to locate them based on one value, then return the entire tuple so that I can work with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `next` and `enumerate`:

```
>>> list1 = [(12, "AB", "CD"), (13, "EF", "GH"), (14, "IJ", "KL")]
>>> next(i for i,x in enumerate(list1) if 13 in x)
1
```

With a simple for-loop:

```
for i, item in enumerate(list1):
     if 13 in item:
         print i
         break
...         
1
```

**Update:**

If the first item in each tuple is unique and you're doing this multiple times then create a dict first. Dicts provide `O(1)` lookup while lists `O(N)`

```
>>> list1 = [(12, "AB", "CD"), (13, "EF", "GH"), (14, "IJ", "KL")]
>>> dic = {x[0]:x[1:]  for x in list1}
```

Accessing items:

```
>>> dic[12]
('AB', 'CD')
>>> dic[14]
('IJ', 'KL')
#checking key existence
>>> if 17 in dic:          #if a key exists in dic then do something
       #then do something
```

Comment: Thank you.  Which of these would yield better performance?  The list can potentially contain tens of thousands of records.

Comment: @user2259908 Both of them are `O(N)` approaches, the difference is going to be very less. Second one is a bit more readable.

Comment: @user2259908 If the first item is unique in each tuple and you're doing this multiple times then I'd suggest you to create a dictionary for improved performance.

Comment: Converting back to a dictionary did the trick and performs very well.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Given the added criterion from the comment "I really don't care where they are in the list" the task becomes much easier and far more obvious

```
def get_ids(id, tuple_list):
    """returns members from tuple_list whose first element is id"""
    return [x for x in tuple_list if x[0] == id]
```

This isn't as expensive as one might expect if you recall that tuples are immutable objects. When the interpreter builds the new list, it only contains the internal id (reference) of the tuples of interest. This is in keeping with the original question asking for a list of indices. List comprehensions as used here are an efficient way of constructing new lists as much of the work is done internal to the interpreter. In short, many intuitions from C-like languages about performance don't apply well to Python.

As [Ashwini noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17493187/282912), if the id numbers in the tuples are unique, and you are making multiple queries, then a dictionary might be a more suitable structure. Even if the id numbers aren't unique, you could use a dictionary of lists of tuples, but it is best to do the clearest thing first and not guess at the performance in advance.

As with the dictionary example, because an empty list is "falsey" in Python, you can use the same sort of conditional:

```
hits = get_ids(13, list1)
if hits:
    # we got at least one tuple back
else:
    # no 13s to be had
```